# Why didn't Orko try saying his spells in reverse? - He-Man

Tags: he-man

In Trolla, where [Orko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orko) is from, everything is reversed to [Eternia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternia).

In the [Dawn of Dragoon](http://he-man.wikia.com/wiki/Dawn_of_Dragoon) episode of [He-Man and the Masters of the Universe (1980s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He-Man_and_the_Masters_of_the_Universe), He-Man becomes Adam when he enters Trolla (due to the reversal) and is unable to turn back into He-Man until he says his spell in reverse.

Likewise, why didn't Orko try saying his spells in reverse in Eternia? Isn't it because the two worlds, Trolla and Eternia are different that Orko finds it difficult to perform  magic in Eternia?

Comment: Because if he were a competent wizard he'd no longer serve as comic relief?  Also, he'd fix most plots immediately?

Comment: Because Orko is non-intelligent magician and added for comic-relief.

Comment: Because he's a schmuck.

Comment: Because in Trolla, Orko was a genius and would have thought of that. In Eternia, he's just a buffoon though, and the idea never occurred to him.

Comment: kcumhcs a s'eh esuaceB